# Interactive portions of the screen are not highlighted when selected

Tags: android, amazon-fire-tv

my Submitted application for amazon fire TV failed for the following reason :

Issue 1: Interactive portions of the screen are not highlighted when selected : Rewind, Fast Forward, and Play buttons above progress bar can be navigated and selected but no highlighted cursor is visible.

I am using the default media controller class provided by android and it does not provide this functionality.
I was able to catch the controls but i was not able to add a highlight on key down and remove it on key up. can anyone help with this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Amazon's approval process, not programming.

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be it works..

```
           Field ffwd = MediaController.class.getDeclaredField("mFfwdButton");
                Field rwd = MediaController.class.getDeclaredField("mRewButton");
                Field playPause = MediaController.class.getDeclaredField("mPauseButton");
                //System.out.println(f.get(d));//not accessible now
                ffwd.setAccessible(true);//Abracadabra
                rwd.setAccessible(true);//Abracadabra 
                playPause.setAccessible(true);
                //System.out.println("Fusioni"+ffwd.get(mediaController)+" "+f1.get(mediaController));//now its ok
                ffwdBtn = (ImageButton) ffwd.get(mediaController);
                rwdBtn = (ImageButton) rwd.get(mediaController);
                playPauseBtn = (ImageButton) playPause.get(mediaController);
                //Log.i("imbtn",""+imbtn);
                ffwdBtn.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                        if(hasFocus)
                            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_background_selected);
                        else
                            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    }
                });
                rwdBtn.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                        if(hasFocus)
                            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_background_selected);
                        else
                            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    }
                });
                playPauseBtn.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                        if(hasFocus)
                            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_background_selected);
                        else
                            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    }
                });
                playPauseBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_background_selected);
                rwdBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                ffwdBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                playPauseBtn.setFocusable(true);
                playPauseBtn.requestFocus();
```

Comment: this didn't work for me. i have defined the listeners for the buttons but those listeners were never fired. In fact only the pause/Play listener was fired when the HasFocus was false. no action on the FFwd or rwd.

Comment: you also have to override onkeyDown and OnkeyUp methods to set and remove highlights..
 v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_background_selected);
in onKeyDown and 
v.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); in onKeyUp